# Document missing exception elasticsearch php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to update my existing document partialy in elastic search for this I write my update query that partially update document instead of whole document 
Sample data that need to update

```
    {
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 3.0780919,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "trending",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "bx-1605773",
        "_score": 3.0780919,
        "_routing": "1",
        "_source": {
          "id": "bx-1605773",
          "name": "new",
          "db_id": 1605773,
          "user_id": "u-2",
          "box_user": {
            "id": 2,
            "box_id": 1605773,
            "username": "yahoo",
            "full_name": "Yahoo1",
            "is_private": true
          },
          "status": "M",
          "created_at": "2018-08-30T11:58:10Z",
          "type": {
            "name": "box",
            "parent": "u-2"
          },
          "box_posts": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this document I only update the box name and status of the box for this purpose I write following  query in ES

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'trending',
            'type' => 'doc',
            'id' => $this->prepareId($box->id, 'bx'),
            'body' => [
                'doc' => [
                    'name' => $box->name,
                ]
            ]
        ];
        try {
            $response = $this->client->update($params);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return false;
        }
```

But when I run this query then I receive following exception

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[doc][bx-1605773]: document missing","index_uuid":"h8kvjFk7S0usH3YBO-697A","shard":"0","index":"trending"}],"type":"document_missing_exception","reason":"[doc][bx-1605773]: document missing","index_uuid":"h8kvjFk7S0usH3YBO-697A","shard":"0","index":"trending"},"status":404}
```

Even this query I found on elastic search main website

I don't know where I am doing mistake

Comment: Can you show the PHP code that uses these `$params`?

Comment: @Val i have updated my question please review

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `routing` parameter since you indexed the document with `"routing": "1"` you also need to specify this information when updating the document, otherwise the document won't be found:

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'trending',
        'type' => 'doc',
        'id' => $this->prepareId($box->id, 'bx'),
>>>     'routing' => 1,
        'body' => [
            'doc' => [
                'name' => $box->name,
            ]
        ]
    ];
    try {
        $response = $this->client->update($params);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
```